# Compiling with MinGW- Unrecognized Command-Line Option

Tags: gcc, command-line, cygwin, mingw

I try to compile a programme with minGW.
I use this version mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe to install on Windows XP

getting this error:

```
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
make: *** [XtGlue.o] Error 1
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that option with mingw. That option was only useful when compiling under cygwin so it didn't link with the cygwin library. Using that option made cygwin behave pretty much like mingw.

You can safely remove that option from within the Makefile or wherever it is being set.